# How do you send data to controller with ajax.beginform?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is my method on controller "sale"

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Models.account account)
        {
            Models.sale creaventa = new Models.sale();
            //creaventa.account = cliente;
            creaventa.createdon = DateTime.Now;
            creaventa.idaccount = account.id;
            creaventa.modifiedon = DateTime.Now;
            creaventa.status = 0;

            context.sales.Add(creaventa);
            context.SaveChanges();

           // return "venta creada";
            return View();
        }
```

and this is the partial view

```
@model List<modal3.Models.account>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<select class="form-control" id="control1">

    @{

        foreach (var cliente in Model)
        {
            <option value="@cliente.id"> @cliente.name</option>

        }



}
</select>

@*@using (Html.BeginForm("create", "sale", FormMethod.Post, new {id="my-form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create" id="btncrear">
        Iniciar Venta
    </button>

}*@

@using (
    Ajax.BeginForm("create","sale",new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod ="Post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,


    })
    )
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create" id="btncrear">
        Iniciar Venta
    </button>

}
```

This does enter to method with this does not send the model.

Then:

- How to send a model?
- How to send a lot of objects?

this is my model

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace modal3.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class sale
    {
        public sale()
        {
            this.saledetails = new HashSet<saledetail>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> createdon { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> modifiedon { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idaccount { get; set; }

        public virtual account account { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<saledetail> saledetails { get; set; }
    }
}






using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace modal3.Models
    {

        [MetadataType (typeof (sale_validation ))]
        public partial class sale
        {

        }

        public  class sale_validation
        {

            //2015-06-17 22:07:26.353   2015-06-17 22:07:26.353 1   1
            [Display (Name="")]
            [HiddenInput (DisplayValue =false )]
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> createdon { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "")]
            [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> modifiedon { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "")]
            [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
            public Nullable<int> status { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> idaccount { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: In your `AJAX FORM` I do not see any controls (which needs to be posted to server), so what are you trying to post? Can you remove commented code and format your code and tell us what you are trying to do in code, so that I can work on a sample for you.

Comment: I dont know but  I believe you didn't see it  @using (
    Ajax.BeginForm("create","sale",new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod ="Post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,


    })
    )
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create" id="btncrear">
        Iniciar Venta
    </button>

}

Comment: I saw that code, but in the `AJAX FORM` there are no controls, so what you are trying to post?

Comment: I want to post  the model object but more than nothing i want to know how to send any data.

Comment: this does enter to the controller method but nothing is passed,

Comment: yes, nothing will be passed because there was nothing in the ajax form. Add the controls of `Account` model using Html.EditorFor etc., Then the values entered will be posted to controller action. If all you want is to post `Account` model ,then update question with the model details, I will give you a sample as answer.

Comment: I have added but i would like to know how to send any data not only a model, is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81075/discussion-between-ramiramilu-and-angel).

Comment: yes as a basic solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you understand how `AJAX FORM` works, I created below code -

Lets say our model -

```
public class Sale
{
    public string SaleOwner { get; set; }    
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I created `two` controller actions -

```
 public ActionResult adatas()
 {
     return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Create(Sale s)
 {
      return Json("true");
 }
```

The first controller action return following view -

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.Sale

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Sale", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "done"
}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SaleOwner)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Account.Name)

    <input type="submit" value="click" />
}

<div id="done">
</div>
```

View Renders as follows -

[image]

Once we click on button, with breakpoints in the code -

[image]

Once AJAX POST happens, output would be -

[image]